# How do you "show off" your web development work?

Tags: portfolio

I have searched quite a bit and haven't found an answer yet. I am learning to develop websites and am ready to put together a portfolio of everything that I have been building. My question is, what is the best/most cost effective way to display my work? I have bought several domain names and hosting for them but it's getting expensive. I want to be able to make a portfolio of my work without buying a domain name/hosting for each of them. I know I can take screes shots but this doesn't show many details of the site. Maybe host them on my own computer since they won't have much traffic? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use one domain and one host.  Point subdomains for each demo at the same host, and run multiple web servers on that host.  US$5 a month for a server on something like digitalocean shouldn't break the bank if you're actually serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=4e0a56402821). Digital Ocean offers very cheap and reliable server hosting so that you can do exactly what you want with your hosting. Also, with a click of a button you can install something like LAMP (Apache, MySQL, PHP). This can show your full completed projects and all of your code, unlike GitHub Pages. Also, I know 512MB of RAM my not seem like much, but it is plenty for a basic web server. And 20GB Should be good unless you also are looking for a filesystem.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Having a personal website/portfolio is great, and you only have to pay for your own domain, which is usually about $10/year. A great free option -- that also has the benefit of showing off all your code -- is hosting projects on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com).